# how to add a simple web page to a Windows service developed in c#

Tags: c#, windows, service

I've developed a Windows service. It installs, runs and serves its purpose. To view the results it produces, I'd like to add a simple web page with Select * from the database the services works with.

Would someone please elaborate on how to make Windows service serve a web page?

Ideally, I'd like to learn from the code of a similar project

ps. IIS is already installed on the host where the service runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out easier than I thought https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUPg41kG_kw&ab_channel=BoostMyTool

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved something like this by making use of the [Worker Services in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) and configuring the service to run as a [Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

And because I had a worker service in .NET Core, I could easily add HTTP workloads like MVC or Blazor.

In my example, I had a windows service running worker tasks as well as a Blazor UI to show the details of what was happening (I scaffolded the Blazor code fist and then added the worker via `AddHostedService`).

The benefit of this is that the .NET Core is acting as the server do this process didn't need IIS on the platform plus both areas of the system are part of the same process.

If the above isn't suitable (or requires a huge migration to .NET Core), then I'd suggest using [Named Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication) to communication from one process (your windows service) to another (your web-app).

Comment: Thank you, MoSlo for your reply! There's no need for communication. Web page should not manage WindowsService, it just displays result of its work taken from a SQL database. Still, I'd be interested to learn from your experience if you care to share your code

Comment: Ok, @НиколайКаретников, that's pretty easy then; a separate project to just load and display data that another process is affecting. Regarding a sample: this was IP created for my work so I can't show this specific example but if I get some time I'll make a blog post on the technique.

Comment: Thank you, MoSlow! I'm sure that would be a great post and be interesting not just for me, but for many others. Looking forward to read it...